# How to aggregate only some columns horizontally in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a data frame like this:

```
df_dict = dict(A1 = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.8).astype(int),
               B1 = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.8).astype(int),
               A2 = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.8).astype(int),
               B2 = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.8).astype(int), 
               C = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.8).astype(int),
               B4 = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.8).astype(int),
               D = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.8).astype(int))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)

    A1  B1  A2  B2  C   B4  D
0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
6   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

And let's say I have a mapping for columns, for example `mapping={"A1": "A", "A2": "A", "B1": "B", "B2": "B", "B4": "B"}`. I'd like to aggregate columns based on this mapping, so that newly created columns A and B would have 1 only when any of A1, A2 or B1, B2, B4 columns has value of 1. Columns C and D should be preserved as they are. How can I do that in Pandas? I was thinking that something like:

```
df.rename(mapping, axis=1).groupby(["A", "B"], axis=1).max()
```

would do the job but it returns:

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'A' not 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select all columns and then add `level=0` for aggregate by columns:

```
df1 = df.rename(mapping, axis=1)[["A", "B"]].groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()
#alternative
df1 = df.rename(mapping, axis=1).max(level=0, axis=1)
print (df1)
   A  B
0  0  0
1  0  0
2  0  1
3  0  1
4  0  1
5  0  0
6  1  1
7  1  0
8  0  0
9  1  0
```

If all another columns are unique (and integers):

```
df2 = df.rename(mapping, axis=1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()
print (df2)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  1  0  0
4  1  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  1
7  0  1  0  0
8  1  1  1  0
9  0  1  1  0
```

For general solution:

```
cols = ['A','B']
df1 = df.rename(mapping, axis=1)
df3 = pd.concat([df1[cols].max(level=0, axis=1), 
                df1[df1.columns.difference(cols)]], axis=1)
print (df3)
```

Comment: What about columns C and D? They should be preserved. If pd.concat is the only way to go?

Comment: @jakes - Are another valuse filled by numbers, so possible aggregate `min` by all columns?

Comment: Had some other (as occurred unrelated) issue, but everything is working now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to aggregate columns based on this mapping, so that newly
> created columns A and B would have 1 only when any of A1, A2 or B1,
> B2, B4 columns has value of 1

If i understand correctly:

- A = 1 if (A1=1 or A2=1), 0 in other case
- B = 1 if (B1=1 or B2=1 or B4=1), 0 in other case

So

```
df["A"] = df.A1 | df.A2 
df["B"] = df.B1 | df.B2 | df.B4
```

If you want delete *As* and *Bs* columns, drop it:

```
df.drop(["A1","A2","B1","B2","B4"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```